# Building a primitive programming language for solving math olympiad problem(TSTST 2015)

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, contest-math, game-theory

There was a 6th problem on USA TSTST 2015:

> A Nim-style game is defined as follows. Two positive integers $k$ and
> $n$ are specified, along with a finite set $S$ of $k$-tuples of
> integers (not necessarily positive). At the start of the game, the
> $k$-tuple $(n, 0, 0, ..., 0)$ is written on the blackboard. A legal
> move consists of erasing the tuple $(a_1,a_2,...,a_k)$ which is
> written on the blackboard and replacing it with $(a_1+b_1, a_2+b_2,
> > ..., a_k+b_k)$, where $(b_1, b_2, ..., b_k)$ is an element of the set
> $S$. Two players take turns making legal moves, and the first to write
> a negative integer loses. In the event that neither player is ever
> forced to write a negative integer, the game is a draw. Prove that
> there is a choice of $k$ and $S$ with the following property: the
> first player has a winning strategy if $n$ is a power of 2, and
> otherwise the second player has a winning strategy.

And solution is made from creating pseudo programming language with using registers e.t.c.(https://web.evanchen.cc/exams/TSTST-2015-sols.pdf)

What can I read about this solution technique? Is there any other olympiad problems, that can be solved like this?

Comment: Let me take an educated guess... Could well be that the solution is a simplification of some actual proof in finite automata theory (or some other computer science field), that the problem proposer is an expert in that field, and that the problem is a simplification of the conditions that lead to the simplified proof. Here it looks like the simplified proof was kept close to its computer science origins while the simplified problem was changed a lot. Of course, I am just speculating, but if I am right then this is not a solution "technique" and is unlikely to appear again in another problem.

Comment: Reading through the problem and the "solution," I can honestly say I see no way in which the two relate to one another. Even Cameo thinks there's too much handwaving here. The proposer should never be allowed to submit a problem again, the committee that approved the question should be fired, and the problem and solution should be posted in math departments everyone with the caption "Please, Just Don't."

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1106809p5017871